# Problematic socket.parser.resume() error in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, error-handling, socket.io

This bug has been crashing my node.js server for the past one week. On average it seems to occur every 12 hours. Normally when an error occurs in node.js, node.js will tell you the line number and your source file that lead to the error. However, this error is so weird that it does not let me know where the error originates from in my source codes. I can't even find _http_server.js within the entire project and node modules. As such, I have been unable to pinpoint and eliminate the bug.

Without the stack trace module 'longjohn', I would get the following error message:

```
socket.parser.resume()
cannot read property resume of null (_http_server.js:442)
......
```

After I installed 'longjohn', I obtained the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'resume' of null
    at socketOnDrain (_http_server.js:442:20)
    at ServerResponse.updateOutgoingData [as _onPendingData] (_http_server.js:270:14)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage._send (_http_outgoing.js:128:14)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:470:16)
    at ReadStream.ondata (_stream_readable.js:525:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
    at onread (fs.js:1744:12)
    at FSReqWrap.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:576:17)
---------------------------------------------
    at ReadStream.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:655:33)
    at ReadStream.Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:522:7)
    at SendStream.stream (C:\XXXX\node_modules\express\node_modules\send\lib\send.js:533:10)
    at SendStream.send (C:\XXXX\node_modules\express\node_modules\send\lib\send.js:480:8)
    at C:\XXXX\node_modules\express\node_modules\send\lib\send.js:392:10
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
worker 1760 died
```

It is worthwhile mentioning that I am using socket.io. I am also using an external service called Global Counter that displays the number of online users. I am running setInterval() in one of the workers to remove expired records.

Could someone tell me the meaning of these error messages, how the error occurs, and how I should solve it?

Comment: And what version of node are you using?

Comment: You may want to test with the node.js master branch as I believe there were several http-related bugfixes that haven't yet made their way into the v4.x branch. If it still happens on master, you may want to file a bug report on node's issue tracker because (provided a third party module isn't messing with node internals) something like this shouldn't be happening.

Comment: I updated node to v4.2.1 and the problem still persisted.

Answer (score 0):

according to https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3508, you may fix this problem after upgrading nodejs to v4.2.3+ or v5.1.1+